# Nginx with subdomain

Tags: nginx, debian

I would like to know how can I have access on my website with subdomain on my debian server ?

Currently :

> - access by IP [ok]
> - access by subdomain "blog.mydomain.com" : I have this error "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" [nok]

In my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default I have "server_name mydomain.com"

When I ping my blog.mydomain.com subdomain, I have the correct IP.

> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name mydomain.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

I check my conf :

```
root@debian:/var/www/html# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Comment: Can you resolve the subdomain by dns? Can you ping or check the HTTP port  like `telnet subdomain.domain.com 80` or `nmap -p 80 subdomain.domain.com` ? And what the status of nginx status, try to run `nginx -t` to check

Comment: @DilsonRainov I can ping mydomain.com and blog.mydomain.com, same IP. I updated my post with nginx -t.

Comment: I have a configuration like that, you are missing the dns configuration. You should config that in you cloud provider.

Comment: @Danizavtz My cloud provider ? Where I found it please ?

Comment: @Danizavtz but I don't want to use domain.com, it was just to test. In my record, I have an A record to the IP server

Comment: @Danizavtz I would like to "link" blog.mydomain.com on my IP 12.34.56.78. Why it's not possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my conf with this :

```
server_name blog.mydomain.com;
```

And I generated SSL (certbot) again, and it works !